# PHP MySQLi prepared statements - checking if something already exists

Tags: php, mysql

For user registration, I want to make sure the username and emails aren't already in use. I have already connected to $mysqli somewhere else in the code.

```
$usr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['susername']);
$eml = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['semail']); 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=? || email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $usr, $eml);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->close();
```

However, count contains nothing. How can I check if something already exists in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change,

```
stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=? || email=?");
```

To

```
stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(userid) FROM users WHERE username=? || email=?");
```

Then you should fetch the value using [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: same problem - $count is empty

Comment: what is in `$usr` and `$eml` ?

Comment: $usr: testuser, $eml: foo@bar.com - this is what I get when I echo it. there is already a record with the same username and emails.

Comment: I use `echo $count` - what am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

Is your username an integer? You can try the following code,

`$stmt->bind_param("ss", $usr, $eml); //ss`

Comment: what does ss mean? the username is TEXT